Pipe delimiter "|" within a string is read with escaping backslash as "\|" in Google Big Query
I have the issue when I write salesforce sales cloud data with Tableau Prep (on Tableau Cloud) into the Big Query, a string that contains a pipe delimiter is stored with an additional escaping backslash.
Example:

I couldn't find anything about this issue so if it's a known problem please let me know.
I was able to get rid of the backslash within further ctes, so it's not that urgent but I hope that this issue gets fixed in the future.

Atleast add a screenshot

I added a screenshot, thanks.

This sounds like a bug in Tableau Prep. Easy to workaround if you know about it, but frustrating otherwise. I suggest filing a support ticket at https://www.tableau.com/support/case so they will know about the issue and can fix it in a future release to help others

Thanks @AlexBlakemore. I will do that.

See this link for future reference: https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D5cw000003Xvc7CAC/pipe-delimiter-within-a-string-is-read-with-escaping-backslash-as-in-google-big-query

A comment on the Tableau community forum is a great way to let other Tableau users know about the problem, but it doesn't necessarily get the attention of the developers to fix it. So I hope you also put in a support case too.
